# SpriteKit Controls / Gesture

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, controls, gesture, hud

Essentially I am trying to incorporate X2 gamescene buttons that do the following functions:

1) Tap to fly (this I have working)
2) Tap to shoot a projectile from Player position (I do not have working).

My problem is I currently have the fly func set when touched anywhere on the screen. I have tried the following :

This is in reference to my GameScene : I thought in order to split this out I would need a node on the screen to reference this function. This does not error in the console but does not appear in the GameScene.

// Button to trigger shooting :

```
    let btnTest = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Crater")
    btnTest.setScale(0.2)
    btnTest.name = "Button"
    btnTest.zPosition = 10
    btnTest.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200)
    self.addChild(btnTest)
```

Next in the Player class I have the following broken down:

```
var shooting = false

var shootAnimation = SKAction()
var noshootAnimation = SKAction()


   Init func: 

    self.run(noshootAnimation, withKey: "noshootAnimation")

    let projectile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Crater")
    projectile.position = CGPoint (x: 100, y: 50)
    projectile.zPosition = 20
    projectile.name = "projectile"


    // Assigning categories to Game objects:
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask =
        PhysicsCategory.plane.rawValue
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =
        PhysicsCategory.ground.rawValue 
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask =
        PhysicsCategory.ground.rawValue

    self.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 300, dy: 0))
    self.addChild(projectile)



      // Start the shoot animation, set shooting to true:
       func startShooting() {


       self.removeAction(forKey: "noshootAnimation")
       self.shooting = true

   }

   // Stop the shoot animation, set shooting to false:
   func stopShooting() {


       self.removeAction(forKey: "shootAnimation")
       self.shooting = false
   }
```

The node appears in the GameScene which looks promising, finally I move to the last bit of code in the GameScene as follows:

```
                override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)            for touch in (touches) {

                    let location = touch.location(in: self)

                    let nodeTouched = atPoint(location)

                    if let gameSprite = nodeTouched as? GameSprite {

                    gameSprite.onTap()
                    }

                    // Check the HUD buttons which I have appearing when game is over…
                    if nodeTouched.name == "restartGame" {
                    // Transition to a new version of the GameScene
                    // To restart the Game
                        self.view?.presentScene(GameScene(size: self.size), transition: .crossFade(withDuration: 0.6))
                    }
                    else if nodeTouched.name == "returnToMenu"{
                    // Transition to the main menu scene
                        self.view?.presentScene(MenuScene(size: self.size), transition: . crossFade(withDuration: 0.6))

                    }
            }

                Player.startFly()
                player.startShooting()

                    }

            override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
                Player.stopFly()
                player.stopShooting()

            }

            override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
                Player.stopFly()
                player.stopShooting()

            }

            override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

                player.update()         
}
}
```

Unfortunately nothing happens in the GameScene and the node doesn’t fire when the screen is pressed, with the code above is there anyway I can amend this to allow for both ‘tap to fly’ + ‘tap to shoot’ functions. I still can’t figure out how to get the button I had declared early on in the GameScene to appear in which my gesture / touch position can be localised to this node on the screen as oppose to the whole screen in which I have currently..

I can say this sounded more simple in my head to begin with than actually coding together.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the above code does not have any calls to run the animation with the key `"shootAnimation"` and is missing the call to re-run the not-shooting animation when `stopShooting()` and the call to re-run the shooting animation in `startShooting()`. The methods should include these as shown below

```
func startShooting() {
    self.removeAction(forKey: "noshootAnimation")

    // Add this call
    self.run(shootAnimation)
    self.shooting = true
}

func stopShooting() {
    self.removeAction(forKey: "shootAnimation")

    // Add this call
    self.run(noshootAnimation)
    self.shooting = true
}
```

Secondly, the `noshootAnimation` and `shootAnimation` animations are empty actions: they will not do anything if initialized as `SKAction()`. Depending on what you are trying to do, there are a number of class methods of `SKAction` that will create actions for you [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/action_initializers).

Thirdly, any `SKNode` (recall that a scene is an `SKNode` subclass) will not receive touch calls if the node's `isUserInteractionEnabled` property is set to `false` (to which it is defaulted); instead, it will be treated as if its parent received the call. However, should a node's `isUserInteractionEnabled` be `true`, it will be the one that receives the `UIResponder` calls, **not** its parent node. Make sure that this property is set to `true` for the scene and for any nodes that need to receive touches (you can do this in `didMove(to:)` in the scene or elsewhere).

I will now propose an improvement. I frequently use buttons in Spritekit, but they are all subclasses of a custom button class (itself a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`) that uses protocol delegation to alert members of touch events. The scheme looks like this:

```
class Button: SKSpriteNode {
    weak var responder: ButtonResponder?
    // Custom code

    // MARK: UIResponder
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        // Respond here
        responder?.respond(to: self)
    }
}

protocol ButtonResponder: AnyObject {
    func respond(to button: Button)
}

class MyScene: SKScene, ButtonResponder {
    func respond(to button: Button) {
        // Do something on touch, but typically check the name

        switch button.name {
        case "myButton":
            // Do something specific
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Set the scene as a responder
        let buttonInScene = childNode(withName: "myButton") as! Button
        buttonInScene.responder = self
    }
}
```

For more on delegation, look [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html). Hopefully this helped a little bit.

EDIT: Convert touch location

You can convert the touch to the node on the screen by passing a reference to the `location(in:)` method of `UITouch` instead of the scene as you did in your code

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    let yourNode = childNode(withName: "yourNode")!
    for touch in touches {
        let touchLocationToYourNode = touch.location(in: yourNode)
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use `SKNode`'s `convert(_:from:)` and `convert(_:to:)` methods

```
let nodeA = SKNode()
let nodeB = SKNode()

nodeA.xScale = 1.5
nodeA.yScale = 1.2
nodeA.position = .init(x: 100, y: 100)
nodeA.zRotation = .pi

let pointInNodeACoordinateSystem = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
let thatSamePointInNodeBCoordinateSystem = nodeB.convert(pointInNodeACoordinateSystem, from: nodeA)
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks you for the time to review this post! I have implemented as per your proposal above in consideration, this is all working perfectly!! Hours of frustration solved! I finally have the button functions working during GameScene, thanks for the logical walk-through, this has helped my understanding for sure!!